# Odoo xml rpc pass self

Tags: odoo

I need to call method (action_invoice_create) for sale order record. I cant find out how to pass self parameter. So task is to call method for order with id = 12. Here is some code:

```
import xmlrpclib
url = "https://myodoo.com"
db = "mydb"
username = '123'
password = '123'
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
new_id = 12  # id of existing sale order
model_name = 'sale.order'
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, model_name, 'action_invoice_create', [new_id])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to pass `self`, you have to pass `ids`.
`action_invoice_create` expects `ids` as a list.

```
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, model_name, 'action_invoice_create', [[new_id]])
```